# How to change external script url onclick?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, xhtml

I have been struggling to find a solution for my issue. I'm not that of a experience person with javascript, but I am looking for a way to slighty change the external js url depending on an onclick event on an ahref.

Right now I have this in my head tags:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/loader.php?GID=126&go=&sid="></script>`

I want the SID parameter to be set to 1 or 2 based on an onclick on an anchor tag. The loader is called with this piece of code, but the SID would have to change right **before** the loader is being called.

`<a href="/#download" onclick="javascript:Load_126(); return false;">`

Is there anyone that could tell me if it's possible? And maybe point me towards the right direction?

Regards,

Sedoc94

**EDIT 1**: I have been pointed in a direction and figured I could get this done with `jQuery.getScript()` But still have no clue how I should utilize it for my case.

**EDIT 2**: As the script need to be pulled from an external domain, I will have to go with the $.ajax() function.

Right now I have:

```
function loadGame(sid){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.domain.com/loader.php?GID=126&go=&sid='+sid,
      dataType: "script",
      crossDomain: true,
      success: gLoad_12603()
    });
}
```

With an ahref onclick I'm calling the loadGame function, but the console says: `Uncaught ReferenceError: gLoad_12603 is not defined`. It should be working. But I'm guessing that it somehow gives this error because the function only exists in the script code that is returned from the external URL.

Any ideas how I can make it work?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change script src on the fly, as the JS code would need to be reloaded. Why not use simple AJAX for this task? Check out [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get)

Comment: add eventhandler on ajax object onreadystatechange, but if you use jquery read this http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: I just read that, but it says I need to use the 'success' event handler, which what I am already using?

Comment: @LightStyle answer should work. What is not working using his answer? BTW, here using $.getScript or $.ajax as you seems to want to do change nothing

Comment: there is a `gLoad_12603` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a success callback that will be executed when the AJAX request completes. Right now you are actually saying gLoad_12603() with parathesis and executing the function BEFORE the AJAX request is even initiated. You can't just remove the parathesis because jQuery might try to obtain a reference to the gLoad_12603 function before the AJAX request is actually initiated as well. So you have to wrap your call to gLoad_12603() in a function to ensure everything works out:

```
function loadGame(sid){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.domain.com/loader.php?GID=126&go=&sid='+sid,
      dataType: "script",
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function() {
          gLoad_12603();
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: This little detail seemed to do the trick! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

[`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
function loadScript(sid) {
    $.getScript("http://www.domain.com/loader.php?GID=126&go=&sid="+sid, function(script, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        //code you want to be executed after the script is loaded inside the page
        //you can delete this callback if you don't need it
    });
}
```

And use it this way, changing the `sid` on each anchor to have different scripts loaded:

```
<a href="/#download" onclick="javascript:loadScript(126); return false;">
<a href="/#download" onclick="javascript:loadScript(127); return false;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the parenthesis "()" in "success: gLoad_12603()".